# Is twitter sharing callback function not working anymore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, callback

I'm implementing social sharing buttons in my webpage and I faced with the problem while establishing twitter callback function which should check if user has trully shared website. It was working like for a while yesterday, but today I can't get it working. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/pinceladasdaweb/4ZEFF/

```
 window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
    var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
    js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function () {
        alert('Tweeted!');
    });
    });
```

(Note: change 'click' bind to 'tweet' in jsfiddle)
Then:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/" data-via="pinceladasdaweb" data-lang="pt" data-text="Pinceladas da Web">Tweetar</a>
```

When I press "Tweet" button alert box appears immediatelly, not after successful tweet.

Does this also happen for you? Please report. May it be some kind of twitter API bug?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working on that way anymore. See https://twittercommunity.com/t/tweet-event-not-working-after-new-button/56778